# 404 error while invoking a method in webservice

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, jax-rs, multipartform-data, media-type

I am pretty new to webservice. I am using spring mvc and webservice to upload a file to the server. In the spring controller I tried to add the parameters in a multivalue map like the one below

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
formData.add("caption", "Test Caption");
formData.add("file",new FileSystemResource("/home/mytxt");
formData.add("jsonData",imageJson);
```

my httpheader and httpentity looks like the one below

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
final HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(
                    formData, requestHeaders);
```

in the service side my method looks like

```
@Path("/addImage")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response copyFromLocal(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream ) throws IOException 
{       
    return null;
}
```

up to this point everything is fine, but when I use the method like the one below, the method is not invoked

```
@POST
@Path("/addImage")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response copyFromLocal(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition content)
        throws IOException 
{   
}
```

client code is

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
formData.add("caption", "Test Caption");
formData.add("file",new FileSystemResource("/home/txt"));
formData.add("jsonData",imageJson);
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
final HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(
                    formData, requestHeaders);
responseFromService = this.baseAdapter.makeRequest(HttpMethod.POST,
                    requestEntity, relativeURL, String.class,true);
```

BaseAdapter class uses Spring RestTemplate to post the url.

I want to get all the parameters present in the map in controller to be passed to the method in the service side. Can any one help me in fixing the issue? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have specified two `@FormDataParam("file")` annotation,on two different argument,i think it should be applied to only one.

```
@POST
    @Path("/addImage")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response copyFromLocal(
            InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition content)
            throws IOException {

    }
```

Comment: Tried the one you told.getting the error "POST request for "http://192.168.12.123:9090/services/image/addImage" resulted in 404 (Not Found); invoking error handler"

Comment: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found

Comment: can you post your client side code to access this web service?

Comment: Thanks for your response.edited my question.now client code is available.